# Bring preview to front when opening pdf from finder

Tags: finder, preview

When I open a pdf file from finder, how can I make Preview jump to the front with the file I want?

Currently what is happening is that I open the file, but Preview remains behind the Finder windows.

I am sure that this problem is new in my computer, since otherwise I would have noticed earlier (this is really annoying).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it still do it after a reboot?